# Copying string to stack in gdb

Tags: c, pointers, gdb

### Why

I want to use gdb as a way to intercept the `open` syscall and make an application get a handle to a different file than it was asking. Something like:

```
replace-file filea=fileb cat filea
# prints out contents of fileb
```

I can intercept the `open` syscall, but I have to supply a new filename, which should be a string that lives inside the inferior's memory.
I wanted to avoid using `malloc` for this because then I depend on the lib being available in the inferior, and instead store it on the stack ("after" the part used by the process), since I only need it for the next codeline and I have no problem with it being overwritten afterwards.

### What

I'm having a hard time writing to the stack, however.
I know that the stack grows downwards, so I try decreasing the stack pointer by the size of my string, copying the string to the pointer, and then increasing the stack pointer back. I'm having a bad time with copying the string to the location pointed to by the stack pointer.

### What I have so far:

```
# script.gdb
handle all pass    handle al pass
set print thread-events off

set $file_a = "/etc/fstab"
set $file_b = "/etc/passwd"
set $len = $_strlen($file_b)
set $len = $len + 1

catch syscall open
commands
  silent
  # $rax == return value
  # IF x64, $rdi == filename
  set $outside = ! $outside
  if ( $_streq((char *)$rdi, $file_a) )

    printf "rsp: %d\n", $rsp
    set $rsp = $rsp - $len

    printf "rsp: %d\n", $rsp
    call strcpy($rsp, $file_b)
    printf "rsp: %d\n", $rsp
    printf "%d: %s\n", $rsp,$rsp

    set $rsp = $rsp + $len
  end
  continue
end
run
```

Test case:

```
    $ gdb -batch -q -x script.gdb --args python -c "print open('/etc/fstab').read()"
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'open' [2])
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
rsp: -10392
rsp: -10404
$1 = -10404
rsp: -10404
-10404: /etc/passwd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/etc/fstab'
[Inferior 1 (process 25336) exited with code 01]
```

Comment: Is it possible that stack alignment is the issue? x86-64 on linux expects 16-byte stack alignment.  So something like `set $old = $rsp`, `set $rsp = $rsp - $len`, `set $rsp = (unsigned long long)$rsp & (unsigned long long)~0xf`, `.....`, `set $rsp = $old` might work

Comment: @Andrew nope. Although the alignment is interesting because it mentions "strcpy-sse2-unaligned". I suspect the strcpy here is bad and needs to be replaced with something else

Comment: I'm currently thinking that executing code in the middle of a syscall is the problem. The errors I'm getting look similar to https://github.com/mozilla/rr/issues/605

Answer (score 2):

You have your arguments to strcpy the wrong way around.  It's:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

yet you have:

```
call strcpy($newfile, $rsp)
```

I assume that `$newfile` is really `$file_b` the new name you want to use, so this should be the src, while `$rsp` is where you want to place the new file name, so the dest.

You'll also need to store the modified value of `$rsp` into `$rdi` so that `open` will see the changed parameter.

Comment: This was a good step, but it's not working yet - edited with the result. I think I'm writing over another part of the stack because `Function not implemented: '/etc/fstab` clearly involves my filename

Comment: I took a look in the GDB source, and I don't think that this will work currently.  The use of `call` within a syscall catch corrupts GDBs internal state such that the syscall does not complete correctly.  I think the answer might be to write a python helper function that copies the string to the stack one byte at a time, so you can avoid the use of `call`.

Comment: can you link me to the source? Sounds very interesting

Comment: @Nitz I think this is a good starting point https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/linux-nat.c;h=cbf94ed03d219f35a88fe5095b021d51a208f1c6;hb=HEAD#l1901 if you turn on 'set debug infrun 1' & 'set debug lin-lwp 1' you can see that `lp->syscall_state` which is expected to cache state between syscall entry & exit is being corrupted when you use a call (while stopped at syscall entry).  If you use gdb on gdb and place a watch point on `lp->syscall_state` it should be easy enough to see exactly where that's happening.